# How does server identify user with the session_id?

Tags: session, server, ip

I don't quite understand how this happens. For example:

1. Some user visits some site (user sends a request to server). The server sends a response along with a unique `session_id`.
2. The user passes authorization.
3. The user is logged into their account. There user sends different requests to the server.

How does the server understand that all requests are from the same client? Relatively speaking, does the server note in some kind of temporary storage (it's valid only for the duration of the session) that some `user_id` must be opened with some `session_id`? And does the server use ip address to identify user?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to referring to a web service.

The login process either sets an HTTP cookie containing the session_id or that ID is passed along as a URL parameter.

Since you've tagged your question with `ip`, you can't use the client IP address for managing the session due to the ubiquity of NAT.